# DST offset dont work in my develop server

Tags: java, dst

My production server is running java8, and my develop box too. I run this and...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Santiago");
    Calendar st = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    st.set(2008, Calendar.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    end.set(2028, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31, 23, 59, 59);


    String actualOffset=null;

    ZonedDateTime timeActual = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(st.toInstant(), timeZone.toZoneId());
    ZonedDateTime lastTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(end.toInstant(), timeZone.toZoneId());

    do {
        if (!timeActual.getOffset().getId().equals(actualOffset)) {
            actualOffset=timeActual.getOffset().getId();
            System.out.println("Offset changed. " + timeActual.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + timeActual.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR) + "/" + timeActual.get(ChronoField.YEAR) + ". New value " + actualOffset);
        }
        timeActual = timeActual.plusDays(1);
    } while (timeActual.isBefore(lastTime));
}
```

I got in develop :

```
Offset changed. 1/1/2008. New value -03:00
Offset changed. 30/3/2008. New value -04:00
Offset changed. 12/10/2008. New value -03:00
...
```

but if I run in production I got only one line:

```
Offset changed. 1/1/2008. New value -03:00
```

Whats happen? My production server in under docker, It could be that?

Comment: Have you checked the image's offset and default timezone?

Comment: Could be that one of the environments needs to have it time zone database updated? [Timezone Updater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)

Comment: BTW, since you are using Java 8 and `ZonedDateTime` and the other java.time classes are thus built in, I recommend you avoid the outdated classes `Calendar` and `TimeZone` completely. Use for example `ZoneId.of("America/Santiago")` and `ZonedDateTime.of(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Ummmm ... it's even weirder. It is working correctly until 2014 / September ... from there, the offset calculation does not work anymore. Is it possible that the DST changes are in some history table?

Comment: FWIW on my Java 1.8.0_60 I get 15 changes between 2008 and 2014 (inclusive). On 1.8.0_131 I get 41 changes between 2008 and 2028.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because (at least) one of your installations has outdated time zone data for Chile.

From Wikipedia we can see that the politicians have changed the rules a couple of times in recent years, which would explain that some installations can have outdated time zone data. A Java installation isn’t automagically updated when politicians change their minds.

The solution is to use the Timezone Updater Tool to update the time zone database of your Java installation. Upgrading to the newest Java version you can get may be another option, you can try it if you prefer.

**Links**

- [Wikipedia article: Time in Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Chile)
- [Timezone Updater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)